# How to Add the .cpp file in xcode project 

Tags: iphone

How to Add the .cpp file in xcode project and which setting i have to do in the project.
pls help.

Answer (score 2):

Go to new file>>c and c++ (under mac os) and then select c++ file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

Simply go to add new file

Under Mac OSX chose other,now from right pane chose Empty File.

Rename this file adding extension .CPP to this file.

This will turn out to be your .CPP file.